# How to read 64 bit registry in 32 bit cmd?

Tags: vbscript, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, sccm

How to read a registry value or check if the registry exists from a 64 bit registry hive with 32 bit cmd in 64 bit machine through vbscript.Because sccm uses 32 bit cmd

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for this. First of all if you have SCCM 2012 you can use an application instead of a package/program. Applications should be executed in 64Bit on appropriate machines.

If you need a package, and you only ever want to execute this on 64Bit machines (either because you only have those or because you make a several package with special environment settings limiting it to only 64Bit) you can use [sysnative](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Sysnative is a hardlink in C:\windows you can use to force an access to the native system32 folder, not the emulated WoW64 one.
So you would use `C:\Windows\sysnative\wscript.exe <path to your script>` as path of your programs executable, the script would be executed with the 64Bit scripting host and therefore the registry access yould work. Unfortunately MS missed the opportunity to include sysnative on 32Bit machines as well so on those systems it would not work.

The third possibility is also based on sysnative but works on 32Bit systems as well. If you include the following code at the beginning of your script:

```
If fso.FileExists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe") Then ' very basic check for 64bit Windows, you can replace it with a more complicated wmi check if you find it not reliable enough
    If InStr(1, WScript.FullName, "SysWOW64", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' = case insensitive check
        newFullName = Replace(WScript.FullName, "SysWOW64", "Sysnative", 1, -1, vbTextCompare) ' System32 is replaced by Sysnative to deactivate WoW64, cscript or wscript stay the same
        newArguments = "" ' in case of command line arguments they are passed on
        For Each arg In WScript.Arguments
            newArguments = newArguments & arg & " "
        Next
        wso.Run newFullName & " """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ " & newArguments, , False
        WScript.Quit '32 Bit Scripting Host is closed
    End If
End If
```

it will check if it is a 64Bit machine and if so restart itself with the native scripting host, retaining all parameters. If it does not detect 64Bit it will just run normally in 32Bit.

Answer (score 0):

strValue64 = ReadRegStr (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath64,"UninstallString", 64)
strValue32 = ReadRegStr (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath32,"UninstallString", 64)
Function ReadRegStr (RootKey, Key, Value, RegType)
    Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams

```
Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType

Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv")

Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_("GetStringValue").InParameters
oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey
oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key
oInParams.sValueName = Value

Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", oInParams, , oCtx)

ReadRegStr = oOutParams.sValue
```

End Function